# Why wont my Navigation Bar Center?

Tags: html, css

Why won't my navigation bar center? I've also tried `< center> < /center>` on the main .html text but to no avail.

```css
    #nav ul {
      text-align: center;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    #nav li {
      float: left;
    }
    #nav a:link,
    a:visited {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 120px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background-color: #21AEB8;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 4px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    #nav a:hover,
    a:active {
      background-color: #2BC1CC;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <title>Stats Apps</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="logo.png" />
  <center>
    <h1> Biostatistics </h1> 
  </center>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>

      <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: FYI, `<center>` was deprecated about 10 years ago.

Comment: Use dev tools in the browsers and navigate to the relevant div and see why it is not being centered by looking at the values applied to the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floated elements will not obey the `text-align: center;` rule.

If you know the number of links (LI's) then you could give your UL a specific width, then use `margin: 0 auto;` to center the entire list.

A better option (in my opinion) - is to utilize `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;` on your LI's.

There are some compatibility issues with this method however, but it does support IE8 and up, which accounts for roughly 95% or more of your average sites traffic. (depends on your audience)

To achieve this, simply change the below rule...

```
#nav li {   
   float: left;
}
```

To...

```
#nav li {   
   display: inline-block;
}
```

---

### For more information...

Here is a link to the CSS3 Wiki on [Floats](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float)

And here is a link to the CSS3 Wiki on [display: inline-block;](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove `float: left` and instead use `display: inline-block` for `#nav li`. You can add the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```
#nav {
     text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k6c9qam4/4/)**.

Comment: Floated elements will not obey this rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it like this

```css
    h1{
      text-align: center;
    }
    #nav ul {
      padding: 0px;
      text-align: center;
      list-style: none;
    }
    #nav li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #nav a:link,
    a:visited {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 120px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background-color: #21AEB8;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 4px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    #nav a:hover,
    a:active {
      background-color: #2BC1CC;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <title>Stats Apps</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="logo.png" />
  
    <h1> Biostatistics </h1> 
  
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>

      <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use to ways to center the h1:

Just centering the text
By using `text-align:center;`

Centering the whole tag first giving a size.

```
margin:auto;
width:200px;
```

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/bj1rta3w/

Comment: While OP's use of the <center> tags is definitely not best practice, this doesn't solve the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace "display: block" to "inline-block" in:

```
#nav a:link, a:visited {
  display: block;
  /* other rules... */
}
```

Remove "float: left" and add "display: inline" to:

```
#nav li {
  float: left;
  /* other rules... */
}
```

Here is working:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEong

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#nav {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Or this

```
#nav {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

One or both will work depending on your page layout

Comment: margin: 0 auto; will only work of #nav has a set specific width.  Something that is width: 100%; or width: auto; can not be "centered" as it already takes all available space.

Also, text-align: center; will not work in this case because float's don't obey that rule.  He already has text-align: center on the UL which would be sufficient if the LI's were setup properly.

Comment: Missed the float, and the `ul` would have to be `width: 100%` as well.  The better way to do horizontal menus is with `inline-block` isn't it?

Comment: Definitely.  There are some minor browser compatibility issues related to that method tho, so it can depend on your use case, audience, and what your menu looks like.

Answer (score 0):

In `#nav ul` add `width: 530px;` and `margin: 0 auto;` and then it will be centered.